# Image "src" text scrape and tablescrape from a webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6, src

I am trying to web scrape this [page](https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/)

There are 2 problems with it:

1) I am trying to grab the data from the table which is present **package details** tab, yet I am getting no result. My selector path is correct but no output is coming up. The required output is given below:

2) Although I am getting the image "src" text yet I am not getting the required text which is used for the images. Required output is below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = []

response = requests.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/")
assert response.ok
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for record in page.find_all('.packages-specification-table tr:last-child'):
   for data in record.find_all('td'):
      print(data.text)

for record1 in page.find_all('.packages-specification-table tr:first-child'):
   for data1 in record1.find_all('th'): 
      print(data1)  
for des in page.find_all('img'):
   image= des.get('src')
   print(image)
```

Required table output:

Article Number 00361049

Packages 1

Width   74 cm

Height  48 cm

Length 106 cm

Diameter  -

Weight 30.00 kg

Required image output src:

/PIAimages/0618875_PE688687_S1.JPG

/PIAimages/0325432_PE517964_S1.JPG

/PIAimages/0690287_PE723209_S1.JPG

/PIAimages/0513996_PE639275_S1.JPG

/PIAimages/0325450_PE517970_S1.JPG

Comment: This page uses JavaScript to add it. `BS` doesn't run JavaScript. You need module `Selenium` to control web browser which will load page and run JavaScript. And then you can get HTML from browser and use `BS`.

Comment: it seems it use this url to load this data - in JSON format. So you can load it and convert to Python dictionary and get what you need: https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/iows/catalog/products/?catalog=departments&category=10687&type=json&dataset=small,allImages,prices&count=11&sort=relevance&sortorder=ascending&startIndex=0

Answer (score 0):

This page use JavaScript to load data.

This code get urls for images.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/iows/catalog/products/?catalog=departments&category=10687&type=json&dataset=small,allImages,prices&count=11&sort=relevance&sortorder=ascending&startIndex=0'

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.json()

for item in data['products']:
    print(item['item']['name'])
    for image in item['item']['images']['large']:
        print(image)
```

Other information can be in other files loaded by JavaScript.

You can find them in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox - tab:Network, filter:XHR

---

**EDIT:**

This page use JavaScript but BS doesn't run JavaScrit.

When I turn off JavaScript in web browser then I see elements in different tags then in your code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

html = soup.select('div#productDimensionsContainer div#metric')[0].encode_contents().decode().strip()
data = list(filter(None, html.split('<br/>')))
print(data)

# ['Width: 82 cm', 'Depth: 96 cm', 'Height: 101 cm', 'Seat width: 49 cm', 'Seat depth: 54 cm', 'Seat height: 45 cm']

html = soup.select('div#custMaterials')[0].encode_contents().decode().strip()
data = list(filter(None, html.split('<br/>')))
print(data)

# ['Total composition: 100% polyester', 'Frame: Solid wood, Plywood, Particleboard, Polyurethane foam 25 kg/cu.m., Polyurethane foam 35 kg/cu.m., Polyester wadding', 'Seat cushion: Polyurethane foam 35 kg/cu.m., Polyester wadding', 'Leg: Solid beech, Clear lacquer']
```

---

**EDIT:**

There is also `<script>` with `var jProductData=...`and there are information from table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

# var jProductData = {"product":{"items": ... }};

all_scripts = soup.select('script')

for script in all_scripts:
    script = script.encode_contents().decode().strip()
    if 'var jProductData' in script:
        for row in script.split('\n'):
            if 'var jProductData' in row:
                data = json.loads(row.strip()[19:-1])
                for item in data['product']['items']:
                    #print(item['pkgInfoArr'][0])
                    print('articleNumber:', item['pkgInfoArr'][0]['articleNumber'])
                    print('weightMet:', item['pkgInfoArr'][0]['pkgInfo'][0]['weightMet'])
                    print('widthMet:', item['pkgInfoArr'][0]['pkgInfo'][0]['widthMet'])
                    print('quantity:', item['pkgInfoArr'][0]['pkgInfo'][0]['quantity'])
                    print('consumerPackNo:', item['pkgInfoArr'][0]['pkgInfo'][0]['consumerPackNo'])
                    print('lengthMet:', item['pkgInfoArr'][0]['pkgInfo'][0]['lengthMet'])
                    print('heightMet:', item['pkgInfoArr'][0]['pkgInfo'][0]['heightMet'])
                    print('---')
```

Result:

```
articleNumber: 20343224
weightMet: 30.40 kg
widthMet: 74 cm
quantity: 1
consumerPackNo: 1
lengthMet: 106 cm
heightMet: 48 cm
---
articleNumber: 00361049
weightMet: 30.00 kg
widthMet: 74 cm
quantity: 1
consumerPackNo: 1
lengthMet: 106 cm
heightMet: 48 cm
---
articleNumber: 90361894
weightMet: 29.70 kg
widthMet: 74 cm
quantity: 1
consumerPackNo: 1
lengthMet: 106 cm
heightMet: 47 cm
---
articleNumber: 80359844
weightMet: 30.00 kg
widthMet: 74 cm
quantity: 1
consumerPackNo: 1
lengthMet: 106 cm
heightMet: 53 cm
---
articleNumber: 40359855
weightMet: 31.00 kg
widthMet: 75 cm
quantity: 1
consumerPackNo: 1
lengthMet: 106 cm
heightMet: 49 cm
---
articleNumber: 10413953
weightMet: 29.90 kg
widthMet: 74 cm
quantity: 1
consumerPackNo: 1
lengthMet: 106 cm
heightMet: 47 cm
---
articleNumber: 40433247
weightMet: 29.90 kg
widthMet: 74 cm
quantity: 1
consumerPackNo: 1
lengthMet: 106 cm
heightMet: 47 cm
---
```

Probably there are other information like urls for images but I didn't dig in `var jProductData` to find it.

Comment: The contents of the table are not coming

Comment: this code doesn't read data from tables on page. It reads from url which is used by JavaScript - this way I can find images. But now I added code which get item's dimensions  from page.